# ScriptIgnore attribute not working on partial class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, scriptignore

I have a problem using the ScriptIgnore tag on my partial view to stop a property from serializing.

var docs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))

The funny thing is, when I add the attribute directly to the partial class in the .tt file, it works as expected, but because that file will be overwritten when I do a code-gen, I tried using MetadataType

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DocumentMeta))] //this is added so we can add meta data to our partial class..
public partial class Document
{

}


[MetadataType(typeof(DocumentCategoryMeta))] //this is added so we can add meta data to our partial class..
public partial class DocumentCategory
{

}


public class DocumentMeta
{
    [ScriptIgnore]   //We add the scriptignore here because we are serializing some of these entities in client code
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentCategory> DocumentCategories { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentCategoryMeta
{
    [ScriptIgnore]        //We add the scriptignore here because we are serializing some of these entities in client code
    public virtual DocumentCategory Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I still get the same error:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'DocumentCategory'.

Because DocumentCategory contains hierarchical data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tribe84

Answer (score 1):

try `[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]`

Comment: This didn't work for me, I still get the circular reference error even when decorating the property in the MetaData with the above, anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For all virtual Properties you should use the `ScriptIgnore` attribute, like this: `[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]`